# Check to see if a value exists in DB

Tags: android, database

I am trying to do a check if the User-name entered by the user exists in the DB.

```
public Cursor checkUsername(String username) throws SQLException {
    Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, TABLE_USERS, new String[] { ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_USERNAME}, KEY_USERNAME + "="
            + username, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor != null) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

When i return true or false i am getting an Error saying

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from boolean to Cursor
```

i just want to return true or false from the DBAdaptor back to the Activity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function returns a Cursor

```
public Cursor checkUsername()
```

Either change it to return a boolean, or return a cursor.

Comment: thanks for it :) i was checking in the Activity :) changed it to public Booleam :)

Comment: Sounds like your sql table doesn't have a column "harsha"

Comment: but on the sql query its not asking for the column harsha either :(

Answer (score 0):

Try reformatting your sql query and provide the 'where' clause as one of the parameters in the database call :

```
public Cursor getRoute(long rowIndex)
{
    String where = KEY_ID + "=" + rowIndex;
    return db.query(TBL_ROUTES, null, where, null, null, null, null);       
}
```

Also, remember to close your cursor when you are finished with it, otherwise you will get other exceptions.